# How to fix: RSA private key creation from data failed - Swift

Tags: swift, encryption, rsa

I used this struct to encrypt and decrypt a string

```
struct RSA {
    var keySizeInBits = 1024
    
    func encrypt(string: String, publicKey: String?) -> String? {
        guard let publicKey = publicKey else { return nil }

        let keyString = publicKey
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n", with: "")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----", with: "")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "\r\n", with: "")
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: keyString) else { return nil }

        var attributes: CFDictionary {
            return [kSecAttrKeyType         : kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
                    kSecAttrKeyClass        : kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
                    kSecAttrKeySizeInBits   : keySizeInBits] as CFDictionary
        }

        var error: Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil
        guard let secKey = SecKeyCreateWithData(data as CFData, attributes, &error) else {
            print(error.debugDescription)
            return nil
        }
        
        
        let buffer = [UInt8](string.utf8)

        var keySize   = SecKeyGetBlockSize(secKey)
        var keyBuffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: keySize)

        // Encrypto  should less than key length
        guard SecKeyEncrypt(secKey, SecPadding.PKCS1, buffer, buffer.count, &keyBuffer, &keySize) == errSecSuccess else { return nil }
        let result = Data(bytes: keyBuffer, count: keySize).base64EncodedString()
        print(result)
        return result
        //return encrypt(string: string, publicKey: secKey)
    }
    
    
    func decrypt(string: String, privateKey: String?) -> String? {
        guard let privateKey = privateKey else { return nil }
        
        let keyString = privateKey
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n", with: "")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", with: "")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "\r\n", with: "")
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: keyString, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) else { return nil }
        
        var attributes: CFDictionary {
            return [kSecAttrKeyType         : kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
                    kSecAttrKeyClass        : kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
                    kSecAttrKeySizeInBits   : keySizeInBits] as CFDictionary
        }
        
        var error: Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil
        guard let secKey = SecKeyCreateWithData(data as CFData, attributes, &error) else {
            print(error.debugDescription)
            return nil
        }
        
        let buffer = [UInt8](string.utf8)
           
        let keySize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(secKey)
        var messageDecrypted = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: keySize)
        var messageDecryptedSize = keySize
       
        var status = SecKeyDecrypt(secKey, SecPadding.PKCS1, buffer, buffer.count, &messageDecrypted, &messageDecryptedSize)
       
        if status != noErr {
           print("Decryption Error!")
           return nil
        }
       
        let result = String(bytes: messageDecrypted, encoding: .utf8)
        print(result)
        return result
    }
}
```

I used this pem keys:

```
let publicKey = "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCC5Z55jKaiAyKEJ0GYoZesW8dL19SB2A9sKMcmmN89q2sZhL03ub640DMF3rIdBpR+g++qmjwP7Va6iRvNx0USI15R90dW423r7G3+zHvee2kHi9vZ0kkePAZBD5qhw5rsRlAGkXZwkBWFjfwJaA3ISU+ov9MJ39mgmTAa65xv9wIDAQAB"
            
let privateKey = "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"
```

```
let info = "{\"Username\":\"DXCSRAGto$\",\"Password\":\"7U89561Gh2021\"}"
let encryptedInfo = RSA.encrypt(string: info, publicKey: publicKey)
print(encryptedInfo)
let decryptedInfo = RSA.decrypt(string: encryptedInfo, privateKey: privateKey)
print(decryptedInfo)
```

In the decrypt method I got an error in the secKey section:

> Optional(Swift.Unmanaged<__C.CFErrorRef>(_value: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "RSA private key creation from data failed" UserInfo={numberOfErrorsDeep=0, NSDescription=RSA private key creation from data failed}))

I dont have a clue about this error, Does anyone have a solution for this error?

Thanks

Comment: Your data is invalid. Your public key data is something I do not understand and your private key data is some kind of certificate data

Comment: The private key is in PKCS#8 (PRIVATE KEY) format, which contains but is not the same as a PKCS#1 (**RSA** PRIVATE KEY) private key.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.